# ace editor javascript-worker force 'use strict'

Tags: javascript, browser, ace-editor

I use the syntax checking in ace editor (javascript-worker). I need to use the syntax checking 'use strict' mode, but without a declaration "use strict" in the body of the code, 
How i can to configure that?